# run node on an alias file on mac

Tags: javascript, node.js, macos, shell

I've created a simple js file called jacket.js with `#! /usr/local/bin/node` at the top so it can run without calling node every time. That's working just fine.

I also added an alias file to `/usr/local/bin/` and added `alias jacket='node ../../usr/local/bin/jacket.js` to my `~/.bash_profile` so I can run it as just `jacket` from the terminal.

This works fine as long as the file in `/usr/local/bin/` is the actual javascript file and not the alias, but I want to be able to edit the file in a different directory and still have it linked to `/usr/local/bin/`. If the file is an alias, node spits out

`/usr/local/bin/jacket.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { book
                                                                  ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:902:3`

Basically I can't seem to figure out how to run node on an alias file to get this setup to work properly.

Comment: Are you sure that just `jacket.js` won't work? Is it executable?

Comment: Yes, jacket.js works. I wanted to add the alias to the .bash_profile so I could run it without .js at the end. That seems to be the problem. edit: actually no, running just `jacket.js` produces the same error. I didn't have the alias in place.

Comment: Looks to me like there is an error in the `jacket.js` file itself

Comment: The file itself is fine, I just cant run node on it's alias linking to the file. `node jacket.js` works. `node alias-to-jacket.js` produces the error.